# when i second time signup it clears realtime database from firebase in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

When I signup second time from my app It allow me sign up but when I chek In data base my old acc was removed, I really need help in this please your help would be greatful for me.

Here is my Appdelegate func

```
var oldToken = ""
var dToken = ""

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
        
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        if preferences.object(forKey: "dtoken") != nil {
            oldToken = preferences.object(forKey: "dtoken") as! String
        }
        if let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString {
            dToken = uuid
            print(uuid)
            if oldToken != dToken && oldToken != "" {
                preferences.set(dToken, forKey: "dtoken")
                preferences.set(oldToken, forKey: "dtoken_old")
                preferences.synchronize()
                print("ohoh TOKEN CHANGED!!!")
                //Change Tokens in DB.
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here is My Signup Viewcontroller

```
func guidancefromcoach() {
        guard let email = txtEmail.text else { return }
        guard let pass = txtPassword.text else { return }

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { result, error in
            if error != nil {
                self.Alert(title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            }else {
               if self.currentReachabilityStatus == .notReachable {
                    print("There is no internet connection")
                   self.retryAlert()
                } else {
                    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
                    preferences.set(dToken, forKey: "dtoken")
                    userIsCoach = false
                    preferences.set(userIsCoach, forKey: "userIsCoach")
                    authorizedCoachCode = self.txtEnterCoachId.text!
                    preferences.set(authorizedCoachCode, forKey: "authorizedCoachCode")
                    preferences.synchronize()
                    let userItem = UserStruct(dToken, self.txtFName.text!, self.txtLName.text!, self.txtEmail.text!, self.txtPhone.text!, coachCode, authorizedCoachCode, userIsCoach)
                    self.ref.child(dToken).setValue(userItem.toAnyObject())

                    print("dtoken......\(dToken)")
                    print("saved new user")
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromSignupSegue", sender: Any?.self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my USERSTRUCT

```
struct UserStruct {
    let ref: DatabaseReference?
    var token = ""
    var fname = ""
    var lname = ""
    var email = ""
    var phone = ""
    var coachCode = ""
    var authorizedCoachCode = ""
    var isCoach = false
    
    init(_ token:String, _ fname:String, _ lname:String, _ email:String, _ phone:String, _ coachCode:String, _ authorizedCoachCode:String, _ isCoach:Bool) {
        self.ref = nil
        self.token = token
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.coachCode = coachCode
        self.authorizedCoachCode = authorizedCoachCode
        self.isCoach = isCoach
    }
    
    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject],
            let token = value["token"] as? String,
            let fname = value["fname"] as? String,
            let lname = value["lname"] as? String,
            let email = value["email"] as? String,
            let phone = value["phone"] as? String,
            let coachCode = value["coachCode"] as? String,
            let authorizedCoachCode = value["authorizedCoachCode"] as? String,
            let isCoach = value["isCoach"] as? Bool else {
                return nil
        }
        
        self.ref = snapshot.ref
        //self.key = snapshot.key
        self.token = token
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.coachCode = coachCode
        self.authorizedCoachCode = authorizedCoachCode
        self.isCoach = isCoach
    }
    
    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "token": token,
            "fname": fname,
            "lname": lname,
            "email": email,
            "phone": phone,
            "coachCode": coachCode,
            "authorizedCoachCode": authorizedCoachCode,
            "isCoach": isCoach
        ]
    }
```

Your help would be really greatful Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're calling SetValue(), your old account isn't getting removed, it's getting set to different info. I'm not sure what the problem is but i suggest using this code:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) { (result, error) in
            if err != nil { 
       //error code here
            }
            else {
              guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID).setData(["email": email]) { (error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        //error happened
                    }
                }
          //Success, email has been saved to database
              }
        }
```

You can add all your other stuff to this code(userDefaults, etc.)
but this alone should be able to add a new document every time.

Comment: Without my code it'll work but with my code it doesn't work.

Comment: i tried this code but it's not working in mine do you have any other solution ? @aboud jbara